# How to get xml response by openin url in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I'm opening an url using my browser and got an xml response like this :

```
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Key>cvs/1142</Key>
<RequestId>1F3326A4AAAD2459</RequestId>
<HostId>
0AL/FcwMI2ePg0WU1Cako5mDpFsxKraqXigdxnrKItD2Mf5KX91UpLIEunj2DrU4GMz/ukQQAuw=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

In PHP, I'm using `file_get_contents($myURL)`, the problem is I can't get the xml response like what I got from the browser. So How to achieve this ?
I just want to get the "`<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>`"

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) or [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php) for transform xml to array. And then you can get the message by key: `$arr['message']`

Comment: Thanks... I will try ... :)